# iOS :: navigation bar does not show in iOS

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6, uinavigationbar

In my app i have added one new controller,xib files. I have a web view which shows some html data. now the issue is it is not showing navigation bar anywhere in the screen, but it shows web view data in it. And i can see navigation bar in xib file. below is the code in .m file..

```
 #import "TechTermViewController.h"
    #import "PictureViewController.h"

    @implementation TechTermViewController

@synthesize mydef;
@synthesize defhtml;
@synthesize appDelegate;
@synthesize myWebView;
@synthesize randomObject;
@synthesize preferences;



- (void)loadView {

    // the base view for this view controller
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // important for view orientation rotation
    contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    self.view = contentView;
    [contentView release];

    //Initialize the WebView -----------------------------------------------------------
    CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
   // webFrame.origin.y += kTopMargin + 5.0;    // leave from the URL input field and its label
    //webFrame.origin.y -= 0.0;
   myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
   // myWebView.detectsPhoneNumbers = NO;
    myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    myWebView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview: myWebView];


    [self loadDefHTML:YES];
    //[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadDefHTML:YES];

    //[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}


//make it happen
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self loadDefHTML:YES];

    //[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

//Remove the toolbar if we are disappearing
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [myWebView stopLoading];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}




- (IBAction) doDone:(id)sender {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) ] ) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

XIB::

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: If i remove loadview method then it shows navigation bar but not web view data....why so?

Comment: myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 check that, maybe that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with referencing outlet of the webview. It was not set to file's owner.After defining outlets and removed loadview method it worked.